# SimpleXML to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, simplexml

It might be a silly question, but I am stuck with it for a couple of days now. What I am trying to do is to insert an XML file in a mySQL database. To keep things simple for now I am trying to move just one aspect of the XML file into the database.

```
    <?php


$url = 'http://localhost:8888/xml2/test1.xml';

$string = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml->body);

$body = $xml->body;

print_r($body);

 $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "root";
    $dbname = "xml7";

$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die('Could not connect');
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_templates (template_type) VALUES ('" . $body . "')");
?>
```

Until the last print_r(body) the script runs and returns:

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Sure, I Exist, but I won't get in the database! [1] => Neither will I! )

How can I make these statements untrue? Thanks all for your help!

Comment: `these statements` what statements?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `$string`, the XML, so this is reproducible? My presumption is you need to convert it from an object to a string.

Comment: You are trying to insert SimpleXMLElement object which would not work. Use [asXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) to convert the SimpleXMLElement to string.

Comment: This is the xlm 'code'<document>
<body>Sure, I Exist, but I won't get in the database!</body>
<body>Neither will I!</body>
</document>